# Finding which functions were called

Tags: debug

Is there a way to see a trace of the list of functions called when I go to a certain page? Say I click on the "Register" button on my Wordpress page. It will probably call a set of both inbuilt and plugin functions before actually loading the page right? How do I see which functions are called and possibly in which files those functions are located?

It will really help me customize my Wordpress theme the way I want.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin called Query Monitor(https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) will help you.Also if you write your own theme,you should know which functions are called depends on the page you are viewing.

Answer (score 0):

A much later answer: use Xdebug. I use it with VSC and it works great. This way you can follow the page request as far and in as much detail as you want.

Note also that, in terms of where things live in a theme you want to modify, there are pretty well established norms for this, beginning with the template heirarchy, which you can find in the WordPress Codex.